# How to add an icon/avatar for muc?

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am new to xmpp. I am building a client Android application using smack and openfire server. I am creating the functionality for a person to create a group and add users to it. How do I add a group icon for my group? If added, how do I retrieve it back in my application? I know ejabberd now supports the functionality to add a group avatar. Does openfire support the same?

Answer (score 0):

The [ignite realtime forum](https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-setup-group-avatar/87911) has some related questions. The one I linked should help you to get the job done :)